# SSRS error while report execution

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We are using `SSRS` (Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 12.0.4100.1) to generate report in CSV format.

Its giving error as below :

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Unable to translate Unicode character \uDD9C at index 17 to specified code page.
```

We found issue is because of below value.

In SQL server we have value in one of the field like this :

```
'hq6SEaPtfixyXs⟨ယԓ僧톭ʨᔑꌽῼ村鋶䈋=='
```

But how can we resolve it ? (as the same value is present in SQL sever but we not able to generate report)

**Note:** We are able to generate Report with Unicode Data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV export is supposed to be set to accept UTF by default, but check your RSReportServer.config file to see if someone changed it to ASCII. If these characters are not valid then you can strip them out in your report query (let us know if you need help).